# Synchronous XMLHTTP Request warning, Jquery $.ajax and how to avoid it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script on a modal dialog along with three script references. When the modal is loaded I see the following warning on the console.

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience.

I have read a few threads here and tried to fiddle the JS with no joy so far, also added **async: true** but that didn't change anything. Also, upgraded the Jquery to the latest as I found in another thread that it fix the issue but still no joy.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#error').html('');
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                method: 'POST',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.IsError) {
                        $('#error').html('<p>' + data.Message + '</p>');
                    } else {
                        window.location = data.Url;

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I remove the script references above the function then the warning disappears but I want to understand how to write the function to asynchronously handle the data?

On the console, it's highlighting the Jquery file.

```
xhr.open( options.type, options.url, options.async, options.username, options.password );
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Does the console also display the source file of the error?

Comment: It's pointing to the jquery file and when I expand it's highlighted the line below.
xhr.open( options.type, options.url, options.async, options.username, options.password ); Just updated the question with this info. Thanks Michael.

Comment: It is an warning that happens with jQuery, it does not happen with 3.x version if I remember right.

Comment: I updated to 3.X but still got the error, unfortunately.

Comment: I just added a console log outside the $.ajax and another inside the success method and the one outside fired first then the one inside success. Does that not mean this is async?

Comment: `async: true` is the default. Do you use `$.ajaxStart()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` to change the default settings?

Comment: What's in those `unobtrusive` scripts? I suspect one of them is changing the jQuery AJAX default.

Comment: Thanks Barmar - I couldn't find those settings on the unobtrusive scripts..Just to prove if there's anything in the unobtrusive files that affect the ajax, I removed all three references and then linked an empty script file instead - still getting the same warning...